# Правильная команда выхода из приложения Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, cmd, консоль, atom

Ребята поясни пжлста следующее. 
Например, пишу приложение на Nodejs в редакторе Atom, в терминале и 2 часть приложения планируется писать на след. день. Выйти с терминала командой ctrl+c или exit? ну чтобы завтра продолжить работу снова. На след. день при запуске терминала команду node -v снова не вводить? При каких случаях команда ctrl+c нужна? Суть в том, чтобы выйти правильно, сохранив написанное и в след.раз вернуться к тем же результатам, в тот же терминал))

Answer (score 0):

```
node -v
```

Это для проверки версии NodeJS

```
ctrl+c
```

Прерывает выполнение текущей команды. Здесь все зависит от того, с какими данными Вы 
 работаете в конкретный момент и что с ними делаете.

Сохраните файлы с кодом приложения в самом Atom, чтобы потом вернуться к его написанию :)

Comment: Приму к сведению, спасибо)